# one winform to add and update data

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I usually in my web projects use one webform for adding and update data. I just scratched winforms environment so I was thinking to use same approach one form to add and update data.

I was thinking to use two constructors on addEditForm like

```
public AddEditForm()
{
   .. to do new object
}
public AddEditForm(MyDataObj obj)
{      
   ... to do edit
}
```

so, is this right approach or is there better practice?

thanks

Comment: I think it's ok, I usually do it this way too.

Comment: @VahidND thaks for reply, one more. Do I need to call InitializeComponent() in every constructor?

Comment: @user2783193 yes you do need to call InitializeComponent() in every constructor. Rather you can chain the constructors like "public AddEditForm(MyDataObj obj):this()" and call the InitializeComponent() method in parameterless constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in my comment I use this approach too, of course when I'm not using MVP(which is a different story)

About calling InitializeComponent() you need it in your form construction because it is the method which (as you can tell from it's name) initializes your form and controls on it and without it you'll get an empty form.

But if you are concerned about calling InitializeComponent() twice, I prefer this:

```
MyDataObj _myObject;
public AddEditForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

public AddEditForm(MyDataObj obj)
    :this()
{      
    if(obj == null) //you're creating the object
       _myObject = new MyDataObj();
    else // you're editing it
        _myObject = obj;
}
// Continue my work with _myObject
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create different constructors in the following way:

```
MyDataObj editItem=null;
public AddEditForm()
{      
   InitializeComponent();
   //Other common code for initialization.
}

public AddEditForm(MyDataObj obj) : this()
{      
    editItem = obj;
    //Other code specific to editing.
}
```

If the object `editItem` is null, then the form can be considered in Add mode, otherwise Edit mode.

A property also can be made for the same
For example:

```
public bool IsEditMode
{
    get
    {
        return (editItem != null);
    }
}
```

hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

The approach you posted is the normal approach for creating such a form.

---

But sometimes you will see something like this.

```
public AddEditForm(MyDataObj obj, int mode) //1 = edit, 2 = create
{      
   ... to do edit
}
```

If you think about it, this is not a good alternative. It's harder to understand and looks ugly.

---

> Do I need to call InitializeComponent() in every constructor?

Unless you do constructor chaining (which would not work here), yes you do.
Please look @Virus answer for a way to only call it once.

Comment: @G.Y please elaborate.

Comment: Every time you use Enums (or a variable for mode) in an object oriented system you must make sure it is done for a new type and not in order to distinguish between two modes of operation. to distinguish modes of operation you have objects .. which can be oriented to your needs :)

Comment: I did post it as a bad example cause it is very common in many systems and will be used by many developers.

Comment: hehe.. you do understand that all your editions can be seen right?

Comment: of course. Maybe I was unclear. But can you see my first sentence in the first version? "The approach you posted is the normal approach for creating such a form." Refering to the OPs approach (should be clear).

Answer (score 0):

The correct approach would be:

```
public partial class CustomerForm: Form
{
    private object instance;

    public CustomerForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        SetData(BLL.CreateNewEmptyObject());
    }

    public CustomerForm(object details)
        : this()
    {
        SetData(details);
    }

    public void SetData(object details)
    {
        instance = details;
        //bind the details to controls 
    }

    private void Save()
    {
        BLL.Save(instance);
    }

   public bool EnableEdit {get{... 
}
```

Usage Examples:

```
    var newCustomerFrm = new CustomerForm();

    var existingCustomerFrmReadOnly = new CustomerForm(BLL.GetCustomerById("123"))
    {
        EnableEdit = false
    };

    var existingCustomerFrmToEdit = new CustomerForm(BLL.GetCustomerById("123"))
    {
        EnableEdit = true
    };
```

Comment: sure, will add to the answer in few secs.

Comment: @Anubis1233 There you go :)

Comment: Please explain me how this is not creating a new object. Oh and this is different from the orginal answer which would not compile.

Comment: Who said there is a problem in creating a new object? and who said the original answer will not compile?? he asked for a correct approach - hence my answer. your answer was focusing on the incorrect approach and still is..

Comment: In my opinion it's not good to create a new object in that context. I'm saying your orginal answer would not work. The updated answer would work but is ugly. See the accepted answer for a approach similiar to yours, but working.

Comment: New instance tactic is correct - it is also used in MVP/MVC/MVVM Patterns.. if you wish to further discuss this we may do so in a chat.

Comment: In what way this is better than the other answer? Isn't it just unnecessary?

Comment: The other answer came after this one.. you may check the dates. what is wrong with you?